# Why not singleton instance provided out of box in java?

Tags: java, singleton

You can make class singleton by implementing Singleton pattern. Nowadays singleton class is basic requirement.

Why don't JVM handles Singleton object creation by itself at runtime?

By having marker interface like "Singleton" and creating object instance once by JVM at runtime. Anyways Java compiler adds "extends Object" if Class is not extending any other class. Similar approach can be applied in Singleton case.
This will save lot of time and development effort and discussions around various implementations of Singleton pattern.

1) Synchronized getInstance()

2) Synchronized block inside getInstance() instead of making whole method synchronized

3) Option 2 with singleInstance as volatile member

This will also save lot of time and duplicate efforts if you need to implement singleton pattern in multiple classes(not considering SingletonPatternFactory class which will return singleton instance of any class which is been passed)

Comment: This is subjective - I voted to close. Btw: you can always easily implement a singleton by using an enum.

Comment: Singleton class is not a basic requirement, you should be really careful when making a class singleton. Because once you make that choice you wouldn't be able to change it later.

Comment: Maybe OP is talking about a lazy singleton -- that's the only way those synchonization patterns would make any sense. BTW OP, in most real-life applications singletons are much better serverd by IoC containers than by Java idioms.

Comment: The reason is just simplicity. Compiler-generated getInstance methods would seem pretty magical.

Comment: It is not a *JVM* issue, it's a *java* miss. [Scala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_(programming_language)) (yet another language that runs on JVM) has singletons as a build in concept, so you can define singletones as `object Foo { ... }` (on par with usual classes `class Foo { ... }` which are supported as well).

Answer (score 5):

Let's take a look at all of the steps needed to create a singleton:

1. private constructor
2. a static final field
3. (optional) if you want the class to be serializable, trivial implementations of `readResolve` and `writeObject`

Most singletons that I've come across don't care about serialization, so that third step isn't needed. This leaves you two really, really easy steps.

```
public class Whatever extends WhateverElse {
    public static final Whatever INSTANCE = new Whatever();

    private Whatever() {}
}
```

It's even lazy-loaded, since the constructor won't be run until you access the class, which would only be to get the singleton instance of it. I don't know what your definition of "a lot" is as far as time and development effort, but I don't consider this to be onerous.

Answer (score 3):

Implementing basic design patterns is not the responsibility of the core language, unless there is a compelling reason it should be.  Design patterns come and go -- for example, the singleton pattern is widely regarded as an extremely bad pattern that should never be used.  Even if you decide to use it anyway, do you want an eager singleton?  Lazy singleton?  What should happen if instantiation fails for some reason?  There's a whole lot of seemingly minor issues to cover, but adding this feature to the language is not a trivial change.

By implementing it yourself you get exactly the features and behavior you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an enum instead of a singleton pattern - this is not very complex:

```
public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

Comment: It's a good approach *if* you don't need any superclasses.

Comment: @Daniel true - you can implement the superclass' interface if it implements one and if you don't need the actual implementation of the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic categories of Singletons, those with lazy initialization and those with eager initialization.

Aside from the whole argument on flavors of Singletons, many Java developers consider Singletons to be bad or an anti-pattern. This is probably an area of disagreement among those currently maintaining the Java spec.

Lastly, the same could be said true of most any pattern. There is not a huge need for a language to adopt or endorse any specific set of patterns, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You would not want a Singleton interface, since the interface has no behavior of its own. You would want an abstract class... kind of. In reality you would want something a lot more powerful than just an abstract parent. You need to have a private constructor (or a private instantiation method that calls a private constructor and returns the single instance) that has to be called in the getInstance() method defined in the parent (violation of scoping).

What you are suggesting is something that will work outside of the traditional class system. Perhaps it can be done as a new object type (similar to how an enum is not a class), but definitely not as a standard interface or class.